# Sub setting rows that are +- N entries from a match in a list

Tags: r

I have a data table (dt) that has a datetime column. I also have a separate list of datetimes (L).

How can I return a subset of dt that has +/- N rows for each match of an item in L against the datetime column of dt?

I am interested in doing this generically as possible, so this case is a datetime, but I would also be interested in doing it for factors and integers as well. Ideally this would dedup any overlaps as well.

Basically this would be something like `grep 'foo|foo1' -A10 -B10` which translates to "Show lines that match foo or foo1 including 10 lines before and after".

Comment: Can we have some sample data, pretty please with sugar on top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so as an example

```
dt <- data.frame (dt = 101 : 200)
L <- c (163, 200, 131)
```

then the row numbers of your matches are

```
matches <- which (dt$dt %in% L)
```

Now say you want from 3 rows before to 1 after:

```
extrarows <- -3 : 1
```

Now `outer` is your friend:

```
rows <- outer(extrarows, matches, `+`)
```

is almost what you're looking for, we just

- need to make sure the entries are all valid row numbers (there could be negative numbers in `rows`):

  `rows <- rows [rows %in% seq_len (nrow (dt))]`
- you may also want to get rid of duplicates:

  `rows <- unique (rows)`
- if you want to preserve the matrix structure of `rows`, maybe setting invalid indices to `NA` is better than removing them:

  `rows [! rows %in% seq_len (nrow (dt))] <- NA`

now you return

```
dt [rows,]
```

Comment: Nice use of `outer`.  You need to get rid of duplicates, in the case when two matches are close to each other.

Comment: @cbeleites. Elegant answer. Very typical of your excellent work on Rhelp.

Comment: DWin, thank you! Richie, possibly also the matrix structure (i.e. constant number of result rows per match) is useful. I updated accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to give exact code without seeing your data, but you probably want to use `%in%` to find the matches, e.g.,

```
match_index <- which(dt$some_column %in% L)
```

For now, I'm making up numbers to show how to get rows before and after.

```
match_index <- c(1, 33, 35, 50)
n <- 55        #in practice, this will be nrow(dt)
```

For each match, get a sequence of values from 10 values before to 10 afterwards, skipping numbers that lie outside the range of the data.

```
all_values <- lapply(match_index, function(x) seq.int(max(1, x - 10), min(x + 10, n)))
```

Combine into a single vector.

```
all_values <- do.call(c, all_values)
```

Remove duplicates.

```
all_values[!duplicated(all_values)]
```

Comment: Also nice! Instead of calling `c`, `unlist (all_values)` would be another option.